# why the result of my code is equal to zero?

Tags: bash

I have two files.txt and i like to search the occurences of pattern in the first file.txt into the second file.
the result is equal to 0.
can any one help me
thank you in advance. 
there is my code:

```
BDDSTB="dns.txt"
for line in $(cat $BDDSTB);
do
 echo "$line" ;
 find . -name "file.txt" | xargs grep -i "$line" | wc -l

done
```

first file:dns.txt

```
exportepg.flex.bouyguesbox.fr
www.gstatic.com
mtalk.google.com
refonte.webservices.francetelevisions.fr
2.android.pool.ntp.org
```

second file:file.txt

```
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:14.356479000 CEST    android.clients.google.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.146825000 CEST    appboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.148870000 CEST    appboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.149575000 CEST    appboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.150667000 CEST    nrdp.nccp.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.152548000 CEST    nrdp.nccp.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.153553000 CEST    api-global.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.155464000 CEST    appboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.156511000 CEST    api-global.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.159388000 CEST    nrdp.nccp.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.162072000 CEST    nrdp.nccp.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.164169000 CEST    exportepg.flex.bouyguesbox.fr
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.164169000 CEST    api-global.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.165326000 CEST    api-global.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.167354000 CEST    secure.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.167427000 CEST    secure.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.174515000 CEST    secure.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.180987000 CEST    secure.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:15.992059000 CEST    254.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:17.460775000 CEST    uiboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:17.462692000 CEST    uiboot.netflix.com
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:17.967824000 CEST    www.arte.tv
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:18.443368000 CEST    radioalademande.tv
Sep 21, 2017 13:36:18.600805000 CEST    webservices-miamibox.filmotv.fr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I can't reproduce your problem.

I pasted the exact code you provided, and here is my output :

```
$ ./script.sh 
exportepg.flex.bouyguesbox.fr
1
www.gstatic.com
0
mtalk.google.com
0
refonte.webservices.francetelevisions.fr
0
2.android.pool.ntp.org
0
```

You should check if your files are correctly named. You can also simplify your code :

```
BDDSTB="dns.txt"
for line in $(cat $BDDSTB);
do
    echo "$line" ;
    grep "$line" "file.txt" | wc -l
done
```